# Iterate over data got back from alertController

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I got a problem with accessing data within my alert controller

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Edit Index',
  inputs:this.customIndexes,
  buttons:[
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: data=> {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');

      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data=>{
        console.log(data);
        /*for(let item of this.customIndexes)
        {
          this.customIndexes[item.name].value = data[item.name];
        }*/
        this.postEditedIndex(this.customIndexes);
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

when the user clicks the save button, how do i access the data?

my inputs are dynamic with the array specified like

```
customIndexes: { name: string, value: string, placeholder: string }[] = [];]
```

and the function displays all fields that populates into custom indexes but how do I access them from the data object in the save button handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to `this` scoping of Object literal. Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/76008/

```
class Test1 {
  name = "Name1";

  getName() {
    let test2 = {
      name: "Name2";
      getName2: ()=> {
        return this.name;
      }
    }
    return test2.getName2();
  }
};

let test1 = new Test1();
let name1 = test1.getName()
```

In the end, name1 === "Name2". This is because when you define a function inside another object, it gets that object's this, not the one from the outer scope. It is easy to work around that by assigning the this to another variable (usually `self` is used). Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5nup6cgx/

```
class Test1 {
  name = "Name1";

  getName() {
    let self = this;  //<<<< NOTE HERE
    let test2 = {
      name: "Name2";
      getName2: ()=> {
        return self.name;  //<<<< AND HERE
      }
    }
    return test2.getName2();
  }
};

let test1 = new Test1();
let name1 = test1.getName()
```

So, you probably wanted to do this:

```
let self = this; //<<<<< NOTE HERE
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Edit Index',
  inputs:this.customIndexes,
  buttons:[
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: data=> {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');

      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data=>{
        console.log(data);
        for(let item of self.customIndexes)  //<<<<< AND HERE
        {
          self.customIndexes[item.name].value = data[item.name];  //<<<<< AND HERE
        }
        self.postEditedIndex(self.customIndexes);  //<<<<< AND HERE
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```